# $\frac{f(X)}{g(X)} = \frac{f(-X)}{g(-X)} ∈ ℚ(X)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, rational-functions

Let $h(X) := \frac{f(X)}{g(X)} ∈ ℚ(X) \setminus ℚ$ be such that $h(-X) = h(X)$. Does that imply that all odd coefficients of $f$ and $g$ are $0$? Or can this be accomplished in other ways?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are coprime polynomials, then yes.  Just write $f(X)g(-X)=f(-X)g(X)$.  We must have $f(X)\mid f(-X)$ and $g(X)\mid g(-X)$, implying the result.

Comment: Clearly $f(X) \mid f(-X)g(X)$, but you conclude that in fact $f(X) \mid f(-X)$. As $f(X) \nmid g(X)$ _primality_ of $f(X)$ (or, equivalently, irreducibility) would indeed imply that then $f(X) \mid f(-X)$, but I don't see that that is the case. The "implying the result"-part is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Lacking any further constraints on $f$ and $g$, no.  Consider $f(X) = g(X) = X$.

As to other ways, why not $h(X) \in \Bbb{Q}(X^2)$?

Comment: I edited for removing all constant polynomials.

Comment: Ah yes, $h(X) ∈ ℚ(X²)$ is clearly sufficient. But is it necessary?

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman : $X/X$ is not the constant $1$.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman : The Question does not ask for necessary alternatives.

Comment: Oh really? Why not? Isn't $1/X$ by definition the multiplicative inverse of $X∈ ℚ(X)$?And if not, what is? $ℚ(X)$ is a field so this inverse must exist.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman : What's your definition of $\Bbb{Q}(X)$?  Most recently, I've been using "the set of rational functions in $\Bbb{Q}[X]$", for which $X/X \neq 1$ because, as functions, the two do not have the same domain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105918/discussion-between-jos-van-nieuwman-and-eric-towers).

Comment: If you don't believe you are talking about functions, then the notations "$f(-X)$", "$g(-X)$", and "$h(-X)$" are gibberish.

Comment: For $f ∈ R[X]$ and $\sigma ∈ \text{Aut}(R[X])$ given by $X ↦ -X$, I mean by $f(-X)$ the polynomial $\sigma(f)$. I thought that this was canonical notation on this forum, although I myself tend to just write $f$ and not $f(X)$ for a polynomial in the indeterminate $X$.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman : Then you should consider what $f + \sigma(f)$ tells you about your question.

Comment: For $f = ∑_i a_iX^i$ we have $f + \sigma(f) = 0$ iff $f$ is odd and $f + \sigma(f) = 2f$ iff $f$ is even. We also have $∑_i a_iX^i (1 + (-1)^i) = f + \sigma(f) = (\text{id} + \sigma)(f)$. Now $\left<\sigma\right> = \{\text{id}, \sigma\} ⊆ \text{Aut}(ℚ(X))$ but there the group operation is composition, not addition, so I fail to see what we can say about id$ + \sigma$

Comment: Simpler: Pick any even polynomial $h(x)$ and set $f(x)=h(x)g(x)$ for an arbitrary $g$.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman : So you don't see that $\mathrm{id} + \sigma$ projects $f$ onto its (scaled) symmetric part.  What do you think would project onto the antisymmetric part?